# No syntax highlighting with org-html-export-to-html when executing with systemd service

Tags: html, emacs, syntax-highlighting, org-mode, systemd

I have a bash script that finds and exports emacs .org files to html in a given directory. I understand that org-mode makes use of htmlize.el to color the output of text in SRC blocks, which seems to work fine when executed from the command line, both as root and normal user. However, when using systemd timers to automate this task the output is no longer colored.

```
for i in `find /home/user/dir -name '*.org'`
do
    emacs $i --batch -l /home/user/.emacs org-html-export-to-html --kill
done
```

I previously had problems with getting the syntax highlighting to work when executing the script directly, which was solved when `-l /home/user/.emacs` was added as shown in the excerpt above (`publishNotes.sh`).

Everything apart from the syntax highlighting seems to be working fine, which indicates that both the systemd service and the executed script itself runs according to the timer.

**Service:**

```
[Unit]
Description=Update website

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/home/user/bin/publishNotes.sh
```

**Timer:**

```
[Unit]
Description=Run every hour

[Timer]
OnCalendar=hourly
Unit=publishNotes.service

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess that this is because something is loading differently when run as root than when run under your user account. Exactly what is hard to say from the information given. However, my first suggestion would be to try running the service as your user. Try adding the `User=<username>` key to the `[Service]` section of the service, and check to see if it behaves as you expect.

Comment: Added the `User=<username>` to the `[Service]` in the service file. This seems to solve my immediate problem, though I am still confused as to why the output would be different seeing as everything works fine when logged in as root and executing the script from there. Thank you